# Pull data from different sheet based on ID

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have excel application, which contains 3 sheets (Sheet1, Sheet2 and Sheet3). Sheet 1 contains ID & Name columns and Sheet2 also have same ID & NAME, whereas Sheet1 will be static and Sheet2 is dynamic.

I want to fetch data from Sheet1 or Sheet2. When someone enter ID in sheet3 then i should pull the corresponding name from Sheet1 or Sheet2 and put it in sheet3.

I ma new to vba or excel formula. I dont know where i need to start.

**Sheet1**

```
+-----------+
| ID | Name |
+-----------+
| 1  | AAAA |
+-----------+
| 2  | BBBB |
+-----------+
| 3  | CCCC |
+-----------+
```

**Sheet2**

```
+-----------+
| ID | Name |
+-----------+
| 7  | SSSS |
+-----------+
| 9  | XXXX |
+-----------+
```

If I enter 3 in Sheet3, ID column then it should populate the **CCCC** in Name column.

Comment: Is `ID` unique per both sheets (1 and 2)?

Comment: Yes of course. ID is always unique.

Comment: I know it should be, but people 'works miracles' in Excel and I wanted to know if this must be checked... :). I will post an answer in one, two minutes...

Comment: What's wrong with a double VLOOKUP? `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE))`

Comment: @jamheadart If i want to do these for all the celss means then i need to write formula for all the cells right?

Comment: Just write it in one cell and fill it down. Or if you want to be clever about it use a combination of VBA worksheet change event to populate the cell next to the target cell with the formula...

Comment: If you want to then add a 3rd column, just make sure the absolute references are correct, use `COLUMN()` instead of hard-coded number and fill it to the right too... `=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE))` (see answer below for clarity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question can be answered with a suggestion to use Vlookup function, but I would prefer VBA. So, please check the next code. It is a worksheet event, and must be copied in the sheet module (right click on the sheet name and choose `View Code`):

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, IDCell As Range
        Dim boolFound As Boolean
        Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1"): Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
        Set IDCell = sh1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 2).Value: Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        Set IDCell = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 2).Value: Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox """" & Target.Value & """ ID could not be found...": Target.Activate
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

It assumes that `ID` is in first column (A:A) of the three involved worksheet. If not, the code can be easily adapted...

Comment: Thanks for VBA suggestion. It seems good rather than writing formula for each cells. I also want to copy one more cell called Age and If i delete ID then it should empty the value. Can you assist

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: To empty the value in case of ID deletion, is clear and I can do it, but to also return "Age", I need to know where from... If it is on the same row with the found ID, I need to know its column (letter or number). Should I understand that it is on the following column (C:C)? Adapted the above code to clear the value in case of ID deletion. Please, refresh the page (this) one before copying the code...

Comment: Like Both sheets have ID, Name and Age. Also in future if they give some more information means, how can i configure it

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: OK. In order to also return from the next column, you must use `Offset`. Since now `Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 1).Value` brings the value from the first column having `Target` (the changed cell) as reference, using `Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 2).Value` will return from the following one (C:C). Should I adapt the code, or would you like trying it?

Comment: Can you please update the code and am new for this vba.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: Adapted. But, excuse me, is is something wrong with my answer, since you did not tick the left side code check box to make it **accepted answer**? :)

Comment: Thanks. its working as expected now. So should i need to add `Target.Offset(0, /3/4/5).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 3/4/5).Value ` if i want to add next column value as well?

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: Yes! If you need to return from a different row, let us say, the next one, considering `Target` as reference, you will use `Offset(1, 0)`. If you want the range above, you can use `Offset(-1, 0)`. And so on. The meaning of `Offset` is how many rows, respectively, columns against the `Target` cell. Minus gives the back direction...

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. I have one more question and posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62575410/populate-calculated-values-from-other-sheets-into-new-sheet Can you please assist

Answer (score 1):

I love VBA but for this one I think a VLOOKUP would be a lot more simple:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet1!$A:$B,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!$A:$B,2,FALSE))
```

If you want to then add a 3rd,4th,5th column, just make sure the absolute references are correct, use COLUMN() instead of hard-coded number and fill it to the right too
`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE))`

To do "error catching" wrap it in another `IFERROR`

`=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet1!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE),VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!$A:$C,COLUMN(),FALSE)),"Id not found")`

Comment: Was just posting the same, but slightly too late. I wrapped another `IFERROR` around the function, in case the ID is nowhere to be found.

Comment: Lol I had just added that at the bottom of the answer as your comment popped up, great minds think alike!

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use VBA so there's no formulae on the sheet, how about this?

To add another column to the lookup range just change the variable `lastCol` to whatever column you want!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim lastCol As String: lastCol = "C"
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "B"), Cells(Target.Row, lastCol)).Formula = _
        "=IFERROR(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(" & Target.Value2 & ",Sheet1!$A:$" & lastCol & ",COLUMN(),FALSE)," & _
        "VLOOKUP(" & Target.Value2 & ",Sheet2!$A:$" & lastCol & ",COLUMN(),FALSE)), ""Id not found"")"
        Range(Cells(Target.Row, "B"), Cells(Target.Row, lastCol)).Value2 = Range(Cells(Target.Row, "B"), Cells(Target.Row, lastCol)).Value2
    End If
End Sub
```