# Populate calculated values from other sheets into new sheet

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have excel which contains four sheets (say sheet1, sheet2, sheet3 and sheet4). I want to populate calculated values and other information from (sheet1, sheet2, sheet3) to sheet4. Both sheet1, sheet2 contains ID,Name, Age, Amount whereas sheet1 is static page and sheet2 is dynamic page. sheet3 will have ID, Name, Age, Contribution. once all these values are entered sheet4 should populate ID, Name, Age, Total(Amount * Contribution).

**Sheet 1:**

```
+--------------------------+
| ID | Name | Age | Amount |
+--------------------------+
| 1  | AAAA | 20  | 1500   |
+--------------------------+
| 2  | BBBB | 21  | 2000   |
+--------------------------+
| 3  | CCCC | 25  | 6000   |
+--------------------------+
```

**Sheet 2:**

```
+--------------------------+
| ID | Name | Age | Amount |
+--------------------------+
| 4  | XXXY | 20  | 3000   |
+--------------------------+
| 7  | YYYY | 21  | 7000   |
+--------------------------+
| 9  | ZZZZ | 25  | 5000   |
+--------------------------+
```

**Sheet 3:**

This sheet contribution value will be entered by user and they randomly enter for any user from both of the sheets (sheet1 or sheet2)

```
+------------------------------+
| ID | Name | Age | Contribute |
+------------------------------+
| 1  | AAAA | 20  | 1          |
+------------------------------+
| 3  | CCCC | 25  | 8          |
+------------------------------+
| 7  | YYYY | 21  | 9          |
+------------------------------+
| 9  | ZZZZ | 25  | 10         |
+------------------------------+
```

**Sheet 4:**

This should be auto populate the ID, Name and Age from Sheet3 exactly and Values should be Amount * Contribution (Amount my come from sheet1 or sheet2 based on the ID)

```
+------------------------------+
| ID | Name | Age | Value      |
+------------------------------+
| 1  | AAAA | 20  | 1500       |
+------------------------------+
| 3  | CCCC | 25  | 48000      |
+------------------------------+
| 7  | YYYY | 21  | 63000      |
+------------------------------+
| 9  | ZZZZ | 25  | 50000      |
+------------------------------+
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried in your question.

Comment: You want `VLOOKUP`: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vlookup-function-0bbc8083-26fe-4963-8ab8-93a18ad188a1?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

Comment: @braX I am new to VBA and i am also trying with small source of knowledge.

Comment: Does the "Sheet3" `contribution` is unique per `ID`, or it needs to be summarized for more possible occurrences? I mean, are there more (the same) IDs with different `contributions` which to be summarized?

Comment: @FaneDuru Yes "Sheet3" `contribution` is unique per `ID`. Only one `ID` will come in "Sheet3" either it from "Sheet1" or "Sheet2"

Comment: OK. I will prepare an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the next code, please. It must be copied in the dummy "Sheet4" module.

You must replace "Sheet1_", "Sheet2_", "Sheet3_" sheet names with your real ones. It will also clear all records for a deleted ID:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh3 As Worksheet, IDCell As Range
        Dim dContrib As Double, dAmount As Double
        
        Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1_"): Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2_")
        Set sh3 = Worksheets("Sheet3_")
        
        Set IDCell = sh3.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                Target.Offset(0, 1).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Target.Offset(0, 2).Value = IDCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
                If IsNumeric(IDCell.Offset(0, 3).Value) Then
                     dContrib = IDCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                Else
                    'for the case of writing the ID header...
                    Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = "Value"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox """" & Target.Value & """ ID could not be found...": Target.Activate
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set IDCell = sh1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                dAmount = IDCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = dAmount * dContrib: Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
         Set IDCell = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                dAmount = IDCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = dAmount * dContrib: Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
        If Target.Value <> "" Then
            MsgBox """" & Target.Value & """ ID could not be found...": Target.Activate
        Else
            Target.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents: Target.Offset(0, 2).ClearContents
            Target.Offset(0, 3).ClearContents
        End If
   End If
End Sub
```

After edit:

Please, use the next code. Paste the next code in the Click event of your button existing on Sheet3:

```
Private Sub MyButton_Click()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet, sh4 As Worksheet
    Dim dContrib As Double, dAmount As Double, IDCell As Range, Target As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long, rngCopy As Range, i As Long
        
    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1_"): Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2_")
    Set sh = ActiveSheet: Set sh4 = Worksheets("Sheet4_")
        
    'Clear all the content of Sheet4, except its headers first row:
    sh4.Range("A2:D" & sh4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).ClearContents
        
    'Copy all data from the first three columns of Sheet3:
    Set rngCopy = sh.Range("A2:C" & sh.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row)
    sh4.Range("A2").Resize(rngCopy.Rows.Count, rngCopy.Columns.Count).Value = rngCopy.Value
        
    'Iterate between all existing IDs and process the data:
    lastRow = sh4.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row
    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Set Target = sh.Range("A" & i) 'ID to be processed
        dContrib = Target.Offset(0, 3).Value 'Amount
             
        Set IDCell = sh1.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
            If Target.Value <> "" Then
                dAmount = IDCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                sh4.Range("D" & i).Value = dAmount * dContrib
            End If
        Else
            Set IDCell = sh2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=Target.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not IDCell Is Nothing Then
                If Target.Value <> "" Then
                    dAmount = IDCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
                    sh4.Range("D" & i).Value = dAmount * dContrib
                End If
            End If
        End If
        Next i
        sh4.Activate 'activate the processed sheet, in order to see the result
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I would like to write it the `button-click` event in "Sheet3" instead of `Worksheet_Change`. Can you please asssist

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: What do you exactly mean? Do you want doing that by pressing of a button in "Sheet3"? If yes, it could be done, but  a different approach will be necessary. There is no `Target` meaning for such a code. The changed cell must be identified in a different way and you should specify this aspect in your question... Would you like to press a button after (manually) filling the `Amount` and it to consider the last filled row of the sheet? How the ID to be passed to the procedure to be identified?

Comment: Yes exactly, I would like to have these code in Button click event of sheet3 and it should iterate the rows of sheet3 and calculate the values and put into sheet4. We should take all the ID's from sheeet3 while iterating.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: To take all IDs at each button press? Are you sure? Maybe only first time and put a marker on the processed rows... Please, think about it. If you insist on iteration, I will adapt the code when  I will be home. I am already in my car and in less than a minute  I will start driving...

Comment: I have checked your code, it is doing for only one row. I want to iterate for all the rows in Sheet3. When i click the button in Sheet3, it should iterate each rows of Sheet3 and put the values of ID, Name and Age directly into Sheet4. For fourth coulm it should calculate and put it in sheet 4 (Contribution from sheet3 and its corresponding value from Sheet1 or sheet2).

Comment: Also it should paste it in second row of sheet4 since 1st row is header.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: This last detail is not important, I would say... If each time the code must process all the content of Sheet3, it will start by deleting everything in Sheet4 and rewrite the whole content, headers included. Do you see this processing something else then deleting the existing data and processing again all the content of Sheet 3? I am asking that, because before starting working to the code I need to perfectly understand what is to be done. Maybe, you have something else in your mind and I miss it...

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: Before adapting the code as I understood you need, I would like to clarify some issues: I am not a programmer! Programming is a hobby for me. I am a manager and I have the habit to understand what is to be done and why to make something in a specific way, since it looks a waste of Excel resources. Can you better explain why do you need reprocessing of whole Sheet3 content? Are the initial filled data frequently modified? Which is the process from this point of view? Why such a need? How many IDs do you estimate to have in the three files after, let us say, one or two years?

Comment: Yes. As you said, when user clicks button, it should delete the content of sheet4 and process the sheet 3 data and put it in sheet4.

Comment: I would like to thank you for your understanding approach. Basically this is ti generate the mpp document from excel file. Sheet 1 contains standard user information and sheet2 will be temporary user information and excel will be locked, user may allowed to enter the details on sheet3 where they can enter userid and efforts per month in sheet3, so once they entered, we should calculate total efforts for each user and populate it in sheet4, later it will be exported as mpp document.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: Adapted the button code to work as you suggested. Please, confirm that it does what you need it to do.

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: I commented the code lines, to be easier for you to understand how the code works...

Comment: Its clear my entire sheet4 including headers and not consistent. I am working on it. Can you help me

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: I do not know if I can without knowing what it is about... 1. Does the above code return **what you requested** in an empty sheet? 2. If it does, what else should be taken in consideration for our working one? If it does not, please explain in details what it should do against what it does.

Comment: Actually it should empty the content range A2:N(Dynamic rows) but sometimes it returns A2:N1, so header also cleared

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: This cannot be true! Look to my code, please! It **clears the range `"A2:C" & last sheet row`**. Only columns "A:C", starting from the second row up to the last empty row. Who said something about clearing the range from A2 to N last row? You? if yes, can you show me where and when did you say anything about that? I feel the need to state: **I am not a mind reader!** :) Can you answer my first previous question:  "**Does the above code return what you requested, in an empty sheet?**"? An answer to this question would maybe clarify something for you, too...

Comment: @Vignesh Kumar A: I would like to also state something else: **I do not hunt for notoriety**!  I would like you to answer my questions and better explain your need and your problem...

Answer (score 0):

You dont require sheet 4 to do this.

Sheet1: Keep entire table in sheet 1

Sheet2: Enter id and use formula [=vlookup(A1,A1:D10,2,0)] in name field where you want value of name. Here 2 refers to column no. of sheet 1. This way you can use formulae is all cells. Whenever you change id, remaining fields will be auto populated.